# Read txt file and put all words into an dictionary

Tags: dictionary, vbscript, wsh

I've been working so far on creating an VBScript that can read a .txt document and afterwards put each word in as key.

If lets say "Hello" Appears 10 times in the text I want the value to be 10.
And it shouldn't matter if it is a big or small letter. like "Hello / hello" or if there is . , ? ! in the end of the word.

Example:

> "Once there was a little child, the child was all alone in the world!"

Here I want the output to be.

```
Key:   Value:
Once:    1
There:   1
Was:     1
A:       1
Little:  1
Child:   2
The:     1
```

and so on.

Right now I am stuck on the part to get it into the dictionary with key and value.
And if the word appear more than once I would like to do check if the word exists and if not, create the key and give the value 1. If it already exists, increment the value.

```
Const ForReading = 1

Dim strcontents
Dim objfile
dim Place
Dim dictPerson

Set  dictPerson  = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Place = InputBox("File Place","Place:",     "C:\text.txt") 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Place, ForReading)
strContents = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

i = i + 1

arrLines = Split(strContents, " ")

For Each strLine in arrLines
  'WScript.Echo (strline) 
Next
```

EDIT:

Here is my finale code?

I gives me a "wrong" output.

```
 Option Explicit 
 Const ForReading = 1

 Dim DictPerson
 Dim Placering
 Dim OBJFile
 Dim OBJFSO
 Dim Strcontents
 Dim Arrlines
 Dim StrLine
 Dim Re
 Dim Word
 Dim list
 Dim Key
 list = ""

 Set DictPerson = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 DictPerson.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

 Placering = InputBox("Indtast Placering på filen!","Placering:",           "C:\Users\TEV-E311\Desktop\Eksamen\olsenbanden.txt") 

 Set OBJFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set OBJFile = OBJFSO.OpenTextFile(Placering, ForReading)
 Strcontents = OBJFile.ReadAll
 OBJfile.Close


 Arrlines = Split(Strcontents, " ")


 Set Re = New RegExp
     Re.Pattern = "^(.*)[.:,;!?-]$"

 For Each StrLine In Arrlines
    For Each Word In Split(StrLine)
        Word = Re.Replace(Word, "$1")
        DictPerson(Word) = DictPerson(Word) + 1
    Next    
 Next

            For Each key In dictPerson.Keys
            list = list & key & ":" & vbTab & dictPerson(key) & vbNewLine
            Next
```

Does this look correct?

The first line from the output is the hole line and not the 2 first words?
(On the first line it says Egon Olsen) And in my output it also says Egon Olson?

**Output:**

Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2001. Alle rettigheder forbeholdes.

```
 Egon:  2
 Olsen
 Jeg:   1
 har:   6
 Han:   1
 var:   3
 aldeles:   1
 svensker:  1
 han:   1
 bare:  1
 almindelig:    1
 fuld
 Benny: 1
 Frandsen
 Skide: 1
 godt:  1
 Egon!
 Egon:  1
 fanden.
 Den:   1
 go':   1
 nok:   1
 Egon!
 Hva':  1
 faan:  2
 sgu:   1
 fyldt: 1
 femmer!
 så:    1
 rolig: 1
 nu:    3
 Egon
 "Gode: 1
 gamle: 1
 Franz.
 Hva´:  1
 taget: 1
 røven: 1
 dig:   2
 igen:  1
 ?
 Så:    1
 Keld:  1
 jo:    3
 ment
 Du:    1
 smælderfed:    1
 mand!
 Yvonne:    1
 Jensen
 Der:   1
 kommer:    2
 et:    1
 tidspunkt: 1
 enhver:    1
 kvindes:   1
 liv:   1
 hvor:  1
 hun:   1
 må:    1
 blomstre:  1
 folde: 1
 sig:   1
 ud.
 Nej.:  1
 siger: 1
 Egon.
 Ja,:   1
 Vorherre:  1
 bevares.
 Du:    1
 lovede:    1
 skulle:    1
 millionærer.
 Meget: 1
 du:    1
 budt:  1
 gennem:    1
 alle:  1
 disse: 1
 år.
 ..og:  1
 når:   1
 vores: 1
 alder: 1
      kun:  1
 resten:    1
 livet: 1
 tilbage.
 :  1


 ***** script completed - exit code: 0 *****
```

This is only some off the code since there is 363 words.
But as you can se it makes a Key (Example) for Hello and hello? Even it is the same word?

And it dosent remove the .,?! from some of the words?
 + At the first line, it makes Egon Olsen into one word? What did i do wrong there?

If anyone wants the text i can upload that too, but it is on danish.... :)

Answer (score 3):

`Split` each line, remove trailing punctuation, then add the words to the dictionary:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "^(.*)[.:,;!?´-]+$"

For Each strLine In arrLines
  For Each word In Split(strLine)
    word = re.Replace(word, "$1")
    dictPerson(word) = dictPerson(word) + 1
  Next
Next
```

Setting the `CompareMode` property of the dictionary to `vbTextCompare` makes the keys case-insensitive:

```
Set dictPerson = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dictPerson.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
```

As a side note, I'd recommend using `ReadLine` in a loop instead of `ReadAll` and `Split`:

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Place, ForReading)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine
  ...
Loop
objFile.Close
```

That way you're processing one line at a time instead of reading the entire content at once, which can be very memory-consuming for large files.

**Edit:** To display the results you could (for instance) do something like this:

```
list = ""
For Each key In dictPerson.Keys
  list = list & key & ":" & vbTab & dictPerson(key) & vbNewLine
Next
WScript.Echo list
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me,

When i run the code now i get.

***** script completed - exit code: 0 ***** 

What am i missing? My head is burning out.... :P

Comment: There is nothing in your or my code that would generate such output. How are you running the script? Also, exit code 0 usually means that the execution completed successfully. Does anything not work as expected? If so: what result do you get, and how does it differ from the result you expected?

Comment: Alright, i'll give you the whole picture:

Create a script that can count the occurrence of words in a text file
The application must receive an argument which is the file to be counted:
Text file = test.txt

Sample Output from the program:

Well: 3 times
Fishmonger: 4 times
Hello: 2 times
Me: 119 times

So  basically, i want it to count how many each word was mentioned in the text file.

Thank you in advance

I run the code in VbsEdit(Cscript)

Comment: If you want output you need to add code that actually creates output. The code you posted doesn't have that.

Comment: Can you give me a sample of what you mean? mine doesn't work at all!!
P.S: I am a noob so please bear with me :P

Comment: I added sample code for displaying a list of the results to my answer. Whether that will work for you I don't know. It depends on what kind of output you actually want to create.

Comment: Hey Again Asgar,

I have added my hole code. And hope you can see the problems?:)

Comment: You're still using `ReadAll`, and you split the text at spaces, meaning that two words with a line break between them will appear as a single token. Punctuation won't be removed from the first word in such a token, because it's not at the end of the string. If you must keep using `ReadAll` split the text at line breaks (`vbNewLine`). Also, my sample code didn't handle forward ticks (`´`) or multiple punctuation marks at the end of a word. You may also want to add another cleanup statement to remove quotes from beginning and end of words.